# How to make the last element push the sticky element up

Tags: css, sticky

This is my HTML

```css
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.container {
    min-height: 100vh;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
}
.mysection {
    background: rgb(207, 233, 255);
}
.mytext {
    padding: 50px 0;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background: aquamarine;
}
.myimages img {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <section>
        <div class="container">
            Lorem ipsum dolor si....
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="mysection" >
        <div class="container">
            <div class="mytext">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. ...
            </div>
            <div class="myimages">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/715/900/550" >
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/249/900/550" >
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/124/900/550" >
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/75/900/550" >
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/823/900/550" >
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section >
        <div class="container">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit,...
    </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

I've set the `mytext` div as sticky.
I want the last image in the `myimages` div to push the sticky text section above.

How can I do that?
A pure css solution would be great, but I would be okay with a js or jquery one too.

Check this jsfiddle link - https://jsfiddle.net/wdu8jc2z/1/
It will be easy to visualize

Comment: Try to put `mytext` and `myimages` in different containers.

Comment: I already considered that, but that would make the first image itself push the sticky text. 
I want the last image to push the sticky text. the other images should scroll normally like it is now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```css
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.container {
    min-height: 100vh;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
}
.container2 {
    display:in-block;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align:center;
    background: rgb(207, 233, 255);
}
.mysection {
    background: rgb(207, 233, 255);
}
.mytext {
    padding: 50px 0px;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background: aquamarine;
}
.myimages img {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.myimages2 img {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <section>
        <div class="container">
            Lorem ipsum dolor si....
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="mysection" >
        <div class="container">
            <div class="mytext">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. ...
            </div>
            <div class="myimages">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/715/900/550" >
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/249/900/550" >
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/124/900/550" >
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/75/900/550" style="padding-bottom:40px;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section >
     <div class="container2">
        <div class="myimages2">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/823/900/550" >
        </div>
     </div>   
        <div class="container">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit,...
    </div>
    </section>
</div>
```